# Using Android Studio with Norton 360 Fireeall

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio on a Mac, but having trouble with the Android Emulator accessing the internet. It is being blocked by Application Blocking option in the Firewall.

If I switch Application Blocking off, everything works.

I have allowed Android Studio access through, but this has not helped, so the Emulator must be running through a different application.

Does anybody know which application I need to allow through?